# Delete into SQL Server loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, for-loop

In case of repetition periods, need to delete the second occurrence (15 to 15 minutes), but the query always returns all or nothing.

```
DECLARE @DatAteTemp DATE
DECLARE @HorAteTemp TIME

DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR
SELECT DatAte, HorAte
FROM @TABLE

OPEN cursor_i
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_i INTO @DatAteTemp, @HorAteTemp;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF  (select count(*) from @TABLE where HorAte = DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, @HorAteTemp)) > 0
        --DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, @HorAteTemp) = @HorAteTemp
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM @TABLE WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_i
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_i INTO @DatAteTemp, @HorAteTemp
    END

CLOSE cursor_i;
DEALLOCATE cursor_i;
```

Another:

```
DECLARE @aux TIME = DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, @HorAteTemp)
IF  (select count(*) from @TABLE AS oito where oito.HorAte = @aux) > 0
```

Comment: Your `IF` condition can never be true.  It's like saying `IF X - 15 = X`.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong query!
And this query don't delete lines.

Answer (score 1):

Would never be possible as I was applying it as:

```
SELECT
[...]
CROSS APPLY dbo.Function(Dat, Hor)
[...]
```